# My printer is HP LaserJet Pro m1136 mfp After setting up my printer in Ubuntu 20.04 unable to scan

Tags: system-installation

Driver plug-in installation is required

Answer (score 0):

I share your pain, I really do. I think that this is caused by HP not realising the world moved from Python 2 to Python 3. But that doesn't help you. This might.

Go to: https://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/auxfiles/HP/plugins/
Choose your driver based on the version of HPLip you have installed. If you don't have HPLip setup, then I suggest you download it from
https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip

This will be a text file in your downloads directory, so install with:

```
chmod +x Downloads/hplip-3.20.6.run
sh Downloads/hplip-3.21.12-plugin.run
```

Follow all the instructions here. Let it delete anything it wants and install its own dependencies. Then setup your print queue, all as normal.

Return to the first link I gave you and download **hplip-3.21.12-plugin.run**
Now we install that:

```
chmod +x Downloads/hplip-3.21.12-plugin.run
sh Downloads/hplip-3.21.12-plugin.run
```

Same procedure, just follow the prompts.

I could then use xsane to scan from my printer.

Good luck, hope this helps.